# Python Requests Not Recieving Cookie

Tags: python, session, cookies, request

I have a web bot that is trying to get a cookie.
The flow goes:
I go get captcha, and a csrftoken (cookie)
I solve captcha and send solution to server.
They send back the session id.

The session id is a response cookie; although I seem to not get it in python.

[image]

The `POST` request to the server looks like this:

```
cookies={'csrftoken': 'h1239phtluwrane',}
headers = {'foo': 'bar'}
session=requests.Session()
r=session.post(URL, headers=headers, data=data, cookies=cookies)
try:
        cookies['sessionid']=session.cookies['sessionid']
except KeyError:
        print("Error getting correct cookie. %s" %session.cookies)
```

Then in `session.cookies` there is only the csrftoken as a request cookie.... But no response cookie to be found.

On another note. This same exact code used to work but suddenly stopped working even though I did not edit it. I verified that the server methods did not change.

Comment: How do you get the CSRF token? Could it be that it changes every time and you need to account for that? What is the `r.status_code` value? Thanks.

Comment: `status_code` is returning `200` and the CSRF token does change and I have a search function getting those and I have confirmed they are working. TBH I was having the issue above before and what fixed it was using `session` instead of just checking the cookies in the `POST`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Have you tried making `session.get()` to the `URL` first, before the post request?

Comment: No, but that sounds interesting. What is your reasoning for that?

Comment: you do `session.get()` to get fresh cookies - ie. fresh Session ID. Besides if script behaves more like human then server has problem to recognize script/bot and blocks it. Human mostly first  opens main page, never makes `POST` as first request.

Comment: Good ideas, I will implement.

Comment: I made one session do everything, all of the requests. Because there are some get requests before I make the POST request... No avail. Did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

To get your response cookies do:

```
print(r.json()['cookies'])
#{'tasty_cookie': 'yum'}
```

Comment: `r.json()` returns `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`.